# How to Mock a repository with Entifty framework context and Dapper context

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, moq, .net-6.0

I'm trying to mock using Moq, xUnit,.Net 6, Entity framework Core, I have this Repository:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private readonly DemoContext _context;
    private readonly DapperContext _dapperContext;
    public EmployeeRepository(DemoContext context, DapperContext dapperContext)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dapperContext = dapperContext;
    }
    public async Task<List<EmployeeDTO>> GetAll()
    {
        using (var connection = _dapperContext.CreateConnection()) 
        {
            var employees = await connection.QueryAsync<EmployeeDTO>(
                sql: "usp_get_all_employees",
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return employees.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the employee repository interface:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    Task<List<EmployeeDTO>> GetAll();
}
```

this is my Dapper context:

```
public class DapperContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DapperContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _connectionString = _configuration["connectionStrings:DbContext"];
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection()
    => new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

}
```

and finally, this is my class for testing:

```
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest
{
    private readonly Mock<DemoContext> _contextMock;
    private readonly Mock<IEmployeeRepository> _employeeRepositoryMock;
    private readonly Mock<DapperContext> _dapperContextMock;
    private readonly Mock<IConfiguration> _mockConfig;
    public EmployeeRepositoryTest()
    {
        _employeeRepositoryMock = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
        _dapperContextMock = new Mock<DapperContext>();
        _mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
    }        

    [Fact]
    public async void GetAllEmployeesShouldWorks()
    {
        //arrange
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DemoContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "DemoApp")
            .Options;

        var EmployeeEntity = new Employee();
        EmployeeEntity.Name = "Test Employee";
        EmployeeEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        EmployeeEntity.DateAdmission = DateTime.Now;
        EmployeeEntity.CompanyId = Guid.NewGuid();

        using (var context = new DemoContext(options))
        {
            context.Add(EmployeeEntity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }


        using (var context = new DemoContext(options))
        {


            //Act
            var employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository(context, _dapperContextMock.Object);//here is the exceptioon
            var employees = await employeeRepository.GetAll();

            //Assert
            Assert.NotNull(employees);
        }
    }
}
```

but in the line with the comment "//exception here" appears this message error: "System.ArgumentException: 'Can not instantiate proxy of class: Data.Context.DapperContext.
Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments')'"

I have both (entity framework and dapper) because I'm working with CQRS, and I have dapper for the queries and EF for commands.
Any possible solution? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to setup the mock inside the Arrange phase

```
_companyRepositoryMock
   .Setup(r => r.Create(It.IsAny<CompanyEntity>()))
   .ReturnsAsync(expectedCompany);
```

OR

```
_companyRepositoryMock
   .Setup(r => r.Create(It.IsAny<CompanyEntity>()).Result)
   .Returns(expectedCompany);
```

If you don't setup the mock then it will return the default value.
If you change the [`MockBehaviour`](https://docs.educationsmediagroup.com/unit-testing-csharp/moq/mock-customization) to strict then it will throw exception.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> in the case of the method `GetAllCompanies` I have to create a `List<Company>()` and then return them ? and in the method `GetCompanyById` I have to create an object of `Company` and returns it ? I mean xUnit does not go to the database using my repository?

The short answer is yes you have to mock all the methods that you want to use on your dependency. Since the `CompanyService` is relying **correctly** on abstraction  (`ICompanyRepository` interface) rather than on the implementation (`CompanyRepository` class) that's why you are not depending on the Entity Framework directly.

If you want to test your repository tier/layer/module than you have to mock the `DbContext` to avoid database calls. There are [tons of nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Mock%20Entity%20Framework&framework) which can be used to ease the mocking burden.

Comment: ok, but in the case of the method "GetAllCompanies"  I have to create a List<Company>() and then return them ?  and in the method "GetCompanyById" I have to create an object of Compnay and returns it ? I mean xUnit does not go to the database using my repository?

Comment: @AndresGuillenHernandez I've updated my post to reply to your questions.

Comment: Please do not encourage people to use `.Result` for `Task`. That could lead people to believe it is fine to use it in other contexts even though it is widely considered a very bad practice everywhere.

Comment: @julealgon That's the moq way how you should mock an async method: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Thanks for sharing that reference. That's such an absolutely _terrible_ way to handle this IMHO. The fact that they are promoting this as the recommended default is crazy to me. I understand now it's not on you though but on Moq authors, so apologies for that.

Comment: @PeterCsala I recently found a post with my same problem and I could fix it, I put it as an answer if you want to see it !!

Comment: @AndresGuillenHernandez I don't know what is missing from my answer so please do so

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
//Arrange
        var CompanyEntity = new Company();
        CompanyEntity.Name = "Test Company";
        CompanyEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        CompanyEntity.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();

        //arrange
        _companyRepositoryMock
            .Setup(r => r.Create(It.IsAny<Company>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(CompanyEntity);

        //Act
        var companyCreated = await _sut.Create(CompanyEntity);

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(companyCreated);
        _companyRepositoryMock.Verify(r => r.Create(companyCreated));
```

Comment: Even though the code makes sense it has nothing to do with your question. In your question you want to test the Create method not the GetAll...